# ListActivity - переход из- и возвращение в- список

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Использую `ListActivity` для отображения списка, по нажатию на элемент открывается другая активность с характеристиками элемента, но когда нажимаешь кнопку назад и переходим на главное активити где должен быть список - его нет. Т.е. массив, из которого строится список присутствует, с ним все в порядке, но на экран список не выводится.

В методе `onResume` следующее:

```
// Initializes list view adapter.
mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
scanLeDevice(true);
```

В методе `onPause`:

```
mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
```

В остальном коде не нашел, где мог бы затрагиваться список.

Где может быть проблема, и почему список может не отображаться?

Спасибо

Comment: главная проблема в вашем вопросе - отсутствие кода с которым у вас проблемы. К сожалению, гадание по словесному описанию не на этом ресурсе. [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный  вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена: в примере не там где надо вызывается метод `.clear()` для массива из которого берутся данные.

Answer (score -1):

Самое банальное, что может быть - не вызывается `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` в `onResume`

Comment: Нет, все вызывается